# Javascript function to validate form AND display css loading screen

Tags: javascript, css, forms, validation, loading

I'm a javascript newbie and I'm attempting to combine two pieces of code which are working individually but not together:

1. Validate my form to check that the length, width and height are non-zero
2. If form is valid, submit form and display a css splash loading screen while the content loads

Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
    if (elem.value.length == 0) {
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function show() {
    if ((notEmpty(document.getElementById('length'), 'Please Enter a Length')==true) &&
        (notEmpty(document.getElementById('height'), 'Please Enter a Height')==true) &&
        (notEmpty(document.getElementById('weight'), 'Please Enter a Weight')==true)) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="block";
        setTimeout("hide()", 10000);  // 10 seconds
    }
}
function hide() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
}
</script>
```

My form will call `show()` on form submit. And myDiv is a css loading page element which appears while the page loads.  Again, I apologize if my attempt is way off, I am very new to javascript, and would appreciate any advice to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does there happen anything? Perhaps try adding a `console.log(elem)` inside your `notEmpty` function and check if the element is correct.

Comment: No errors and neither '1' or '2' works, i.e. with empty fields the form still submits and in either case (valid/invalid) the myDiv element fails to display

Comment: Ok, so as I suggested add a `console.log(elem)` as first line inside your `notEmpty` function and check whether you get the right element as parameter. If you use Chrome or Firefox you should be able to dig into the log output and inspect e.g. the value.

Comment: Step one is to make sure that your `show()` function is being called. Put a `console.log('show it!')` in there first to make sure it's being called. Once you are sure it is being called, then you can see if its a problem with how you are trying to display the div.

Comment: On another note, the `hide` function is not going to be called since `setTimeout()` accepts a function as an argument, not a string. If you change it to read `setTimeout(hide, 10000);` instead that will work, but that may not be your main problem.

Comment: @DigTheDoug: I think you may not be entirely correct. The hide() function will get called the way it is in setTimeout.

Comment: @DigTheDoug `setTimeout` does in fact accept a string. It either accepts a string of Javascript to execute in the global context, or a function. A function is definitely preferred, not required though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: @user2037290 Can you show your code where `show` is called and any other relevant code/HTML?

Comment: there's no need for three functions, you can merge them into one. see my answer below.

Comment: Why even stop there. User jquery and jquery plugins to do the job in a much nicer way - http://jquery.com/, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation and http://contextllc.com/tools/jQuery-showLoading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML form add `onClick="validate(event)"` to the submit button:

```
<form action="someAction">
    <input type="text" id="length"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="height"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="weight"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" onClick="validate(event)"/>
</form>
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none">Loading....</div>
```

then try this code:

```
function validate(e) {
    (e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;//stop the form from submitting before validating
    var arr = ['length', 'height', 'weight'],
        valid = true,
        helperMsg = ['please choose length value', 'please choose height value', 'please choose weight vale'];
    for (var i in arr) {
        var elm = document.getElementById(arr[i]);
        if (elm.value.length == 0) {
            alert(helperMsg[i]);
            elm.focus();
            valid = false;            
            break;//stop looping and move to the next step
        }
    }
    if (valid) {
        var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();//submit the first form, or you can change it to document.getElementBY('id') instead if you add an id to your form which would be better.
        div.style.display = 'block';//show div
        setTimeout(function () {
            div.style.display = 'none';//hide div after 10 sec
        }, 10000);
    }

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/thPX5/)

Comment: Thanks very much razzak this is working perfectly and is correctly preventing the form from submitting in the case of missing (empty) form values. Although I'm not 100% sure I understand why your code is doing this (preventing form submission) but MickJ's isn't

Comment: your welcome, it's because the submit button will submit the form regardless to the javascript, unless you prevent it's default action `submitting form` by using `event.preventDefault`.

Comment: I am sorry razzak if sound a bit confrontational, but where do you see a 'submit' button in my code? Sure the 'value' is 'submit' but the type is 'button' not 'submit'.

Comment: i must have misread it, i thought it was `input type="submit"`, in this case i'm not sure why your code is not working

Answer (score 0):

The following is a working solution(may not be the best or ideal), that should work for you as well. Try attaching the function to the submit button. Make it type 'button' attach the 'show' to its click event and modify the 'show' method slightly as shown below. Hope this helps:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
    if (elem.value.length == 0) {
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function show() {
    if ((notEmpty(document.getElementById('length'), 'Please Enter a Length')==true) &&
        (notEmpty(document.getElementById('height'), 'Please Enter a Height')==true) &&
        (notEmpty(document.getElementById('weight'), 'Please Enter a Weight')==true)) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="block";
        setTimeout("hide()", 10000);  // 10 seconds
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    }
}
function hide() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" action="someAction" onSubmit="show()">
    <input type="text" id="length"/>
    <input type="text" id="height"/>
    <input type="text" id="weight"/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="mySubmitBtn" onClick="show()"/>
</form>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried running this but no luck...I will try playing around with the console.log function as suggested above. As a newbie I would definitely appreciate any brief comments on how this could be done better

Comment: See my alternate solution above. That should work for you(works for me). In the meantime I will try to formulate a cleaner solution when I have a bit more time.

Comment: Thanks this works pretty well (loading splash displays on valid form submit, error messages on invalid) except that form still seems to submit for the invalid entry case. I will read a bit more about jquery functions as suggested by yourself above. Thanks

Comment: Absolutely, its always best to learn to do the best possible way. Although I am curious because it was working perfectly for me. As evidence: http://jsfiddle.net/K4EBU/4/ I would love to learn as to why it did not work for you for invalid entry case.